# Pagetitle in top of dnn page

Tags: dotnetnuke

I need the pagetitle to show first on each page.
I tried serch on google and found one hint but it didn't work
Is there anybody who knows how to make it.

Best Regards
Mats

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use ASP.NET inline expression in the skin's .ascx:

```
<%= PortalSettings.ActiveTab.Title %>
```

Answer (score -1):

The best solution is to use this statement on top of your skin:

```
<%= PortalSettings.ActiveTab.Title%>
```

Comment: This is just a badly-formatted version of the other answer to this question.  Only post an answer if you have something new to add.